# Count how many times a key appears in a querystring

Tags: php, count, query-string

Suppose that I have a querystring like this:

```
?s=1&s=1&s=1
```

How do I count how many times the key "s" appears (no matter the value) ?
I tried with

```
count($_GET['s'])
```

but it always returns 1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of `count($_GET['s'])` is correct, because with `?s=1&s=1&s=1` you overwrite `s` parameter with the last value. If you want to pass an array, do it with:

```
?s[]=1&s[]=1&s[]=1
```

then `count` will returns `3` as expected.

Comment: Actually it's php-behaviour that the latter overwrites the former value (same with POST). One could, like BenM showed, parse the query string and count the values.

Answer (score 3):

To count how many times `s=` occurs in the query string, you can do this:

```
$query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$occurs = substr_count($query_string, 's=');
echo $occurs;
```

It is better to follow @hsz's answer though.

Comment: Thanks, BenM, I'm afraid that some other keys ending in "s" (as "apples" or "oranges") could be wrongly counted: am I right?